# Has anyone real world experience or studies about too much haptic feedback?

Tags: haptics

In my application I have added some haptic feedback with important interactions.

The direct feedback you feel when a button registers your interaction seems to work really well.

Now I am thinking about adding it also to other places, like i.e. when you switch to main pages through the bottom menu.

I've noticed some big companies don't do this.

- Instagram has nothing when switching main pages
- Facebook only has a sound when switching main pages (but no haptic feedback)
- Reddit, Twitter and Tiktok neither

I wonder if there is a specific (researched/experienced) reason why they don't do this.

Maybe users are getting annoyed with too much haptic feedback?

But then again by default haptic feedback is also on with keyboards.

Does anyone have experience / knows any research why I SHOULD NOT add haptic feedback to i.e. main page switching?

PS: I did notice that when I used haptic feedback with actions that were not directly triggered by the user it felt a bit annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I think haptic feedback is most useful when you want to mimic physical behaviour or feedback that doesn't necessarily exist normally in digital mediums, which is why they tend to be most useful for game controllers that need to simulate real-world input to the user and make the games more realistic.

In terms of an environment that is by default digital (i.e. websites and AR/VR interactions), I think haptic feedback serves to increase the accessibility for specific types of use cases and users but this is where using them too much causes friction because it over-represents the physical input we need to process digital interactions.

Instead of haptic feedback, there might be visual or auditory feedback instead, or the level of haptic feedback can be turned down more.

It is difficult to determine what is 'too much' given that there are individual preferences, but you should provide ways for such features to be turned on/off, or for it to be turned up/down as required or preferred to avoid the potential issues you raised.